cannot read properties of undefined reading'create' from xenova package
So this is my error :
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
    at constructSession (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/models.js:454:39)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async BertModel.from_pretrained (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/models.js:1121:20)
    at async AutoModel.from_pretrained (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/models.js:5847:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
    at async loadItems (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/@xenova/transformers/src/pipelines.js:3269:5)

And my code in nextjs is kinda like this:
import { pipeline } from "@xenova/transformers"
async function initializePipeline() {
  try {
    // Attempt to load the pipeline with a different model or configuration
    const extractor = await pipeline('feature-extraction', 'Xenova/all-MiniLM-L6-v2', {
      useWasm: true, // Explicitly set to use WebAssembly
    });
    return extractor;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error initializing pipeline:', error);
    throw error;
  }
}
const extractor = await initializePipeline();
export async function POST(req) {
    const body = await req.json();
    const query = body.query || '';
    const query_embedded = await extractor(query, { pooling: 'mean', normalize: true });
    console.log(query_embedded);
}

I am expecting it to generate vectors of my question so it can search for similarity in pinecone
